# Cover Image Cropping Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I want to know exact size of cover image cropping .The UI design for my Application is given below. How i Crop an image to exact fit to all versions android phone.
if i take the exact length and width of the bitmap image .The background thread takes so much time to load image. 
[image]

my code for image cropping is given below, but this is only fit with the image size a lot of blank space  cause in edges.

```
public class ProportionalImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

public ProportionalImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable d = getDrawable();
    if (d != null) {
        int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }
    else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set "android:scaleType" attribute of ImageView to "centerCrop".

Comment: @NavinGupta no change, now also having space.

Comment: If your image's size is smaller then your view than it will leave space.So you have to scale your Bitmap according to your ImagView's size.Or use "scaleType" = "fitXY". But in this case Image will be destorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drawable d = getDrawable();
```

Given internal bitmap size which is not same as original bitmap height and width.
For this you need to calculation height and width itself by using Device screen height and width and according to your ImageView height and width.

Also If you are doing any Crop operation with bitmaps so need to aware about Aspect Ratio of Image and proposed Aspect Ratio. So when you actually cut your Image, image quality not decreases.

Comment: Worked Fine,Thanks